# Jquery files conflict

Tags: jquery, conflict

In my application i am using two jquery files. one for date picker and one for auto complete. but my script is not working for those purpose. files are getting clashing.

below i have mentioned the files that i have used.

for auto complete i have used jquery-1.9.1 file

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

for date picker i have used

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/datepicker/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="js/datepicker/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/datepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
```

please help me to avoid conflicts of files... thanks in advance...

Comment: why are you including two version of jQuery ? Keep one version of Jquery .  Also read [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: remove the older version of the jquery and put only latest version file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just include this files only:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and your code will work fine.

There's no need to include multiple **jQuery** files here like:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

causing the jQuery files conflict issue at your end.